# How to release Android apk Privately

Tags: android, server, apk

We have developed an Android application where we don't want it to release through play store.

We want to host the apk remotely in the server and when a new version of the apk is uploaded to server then users who already have installed the application should get the notification that there is new version of the apk is available.

> Our apk will be over 15MB. What are the best options to store the apk in the server?

Please provide suggestions on it.

Answer (score 1):

**Host your apk on any web server or a file sharing system for download.**

In your app **include a small logic on start to check the current version and match it with the latest version on server**.

The latest version could be stored in the ***db*** or ***a plain text file on server*** or ***the apk file name*** itself.

**If the version on server is higher show a notification** and download the new apk for udpate.

To keep things simple and cost effective it is also a good idea to use ***Google Drive, Drop Box, File Share, Sharepoint or something similar*** to host your apk for download, since you just need to host the apk for download (and may be another file to store the version number, if you do not include it in the apk name).

For **notifications** you could ask the users to subscribe for email alerts every time the file changes. When they get the email notification they download the new version.

Comment: Can you provide names of web servers?

Comment: many like IIS, Tomcat etc. Its up to you to choose one Also a good idea to use Google Drive, Drop Box, File Share or something similar, since you just need to host the apk for download.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it unless you are uploading it to Playstore. i can suggest you a trick,

First Sign your apk by using your public/private key.

Host it in your server.

Share it in your **dropbox** and send the link via email to your customer.

Note :- I want you to sign the app because, by default android will not allow user to install un-signed apk. it will be helpful for non technical customers.